# Send mails on Ubuntu 16.04 - Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using 3 possible authenticators

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, sendmail, smtp

I'm trying to send mails on my ubuntu server (from gmail). I have the Starter Cloud package from [Scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com/). I have installed sendmail on my ubuntu server with the [following tutorial](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/configuring-sendmail-on-ubuntu-1404).

In my **Laravel application** I have the following configuration (mailtrap for testing):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_USERNAME=1f129791a7e29f
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My name"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myname@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=passwordmailtrap
```

But when I try to send the email I'm getting the following error:

[image]

What could be my problem here? Or should I follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) and install/configure postfix on my server? **When I try this on my local environment (Homestead) this works without problems**.

Comment: I noticed that the default security group of Scaleway is blocking SMTP port output in its default settings. See there : https://community.online.net/t/solved-smtp-connection-blocked/2262 Did you check that already ?